# parsing URL in newspaper website

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have many urls from the same newspaper, each url has a depository for each writer.

For example:

> 1. http://alhayat.com/Opinion/Zinab-Ghasab.aspx
> 2. http://alhayat.com/Opinion/Abeer-AlFozan.aspx
> 3. http://www.alhayat.com/Opinion/Suzan-Mash-hadi.aspx
> 4. http://www.alhayat.com/Opinion/Thuraya-Al-Shahri.aspx
> 5. http://www.alhayat.com/Opinion/Badria-Al-Besher.aspx

Could someone help me please with writing a regular expression something that would generate all writers urls?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output.. Something like `Zinab-Ghasab.aspx` or only `Zinab-Ghasab`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `Zinab-Ghasab.aspx`, you need no regex.

Just iterate through all of these URLs and use

```
print s[s.rfind("/")+1:]
```

See [sample demo](http://ideone.com/Yy5vxg).

A regex would look like

```
print re.findall(r"/([^/]+)\.aspx", input)
```

It will get all your values from input without .aspx extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **findall()** method in "**re**" module.

Assuming that you are reading the content from a file

- import re
- fp = open("file_name", "r")
- contents = fp.read()
- **writer_urls = re.findall("https?://.+.com/.+/(.*).aspx", contents)**
- fp.close()

Now, writer_urls list is holding all the required urls.